# How to provision Microsoft Teams multi tenant app for all tenants

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-teams

We have a Microsoft Teams Non-gallery app that supports multi tenants. To provision the app to all tenants the Tenant Admin needs to the following steps :

1. As it is a custom app before all the users start to use the app, tenant admin needs to add the app through MSteams App(Desktop\Web based) --> store -->Upload custom app option
2. Then in the Azure portal tenant admin has to Grant Admin Consent for the permissions that are assigned to app

Our question is

1. Is there any way to automate the app provision without Tenant Admin interaction ?

Any document link related to this wold also helpful

Answer (score 0):

You could automate the steps to [publish the app in Tenant catalog using Graph APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamsapp-publish?view=graph-rest-1.0). However, these Graph APIs need consent from Admin.

Also the Admin consent part cannot be skipped if you are using App Permissions or Delegated permissions with elevated access.

Comment: Thanks. Is the behaviour same for multi tenant Gallery Apps too ?

Comment: What do you mean by Gallery Apps?